# How to print number of selected items from ChoiceType field in symfony4?

Tags: symfony4

I'm making filters for site and have some of them are drop down list where user can choose one or many items. I want to show how many he chose after apply them.

This is how i built the drop down list

```
$builder->add('accom', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label'      => 'accom_filter',
            'required'   => false,
            'multiple'   => true,
            'choices'    => [
                'accom.full_board'         => 'full_board',
                'accom.full_and_sunday'    => 'full_and_sunday',
                'accom.full_board_and_day' => 'full_board_and_day',
                'accom.sunday'             => 'sunday',
                'accom.day'                => 'day',
            ],
        ])
```

I'd like to pring something like this:

```
Accommodation (checked 2 from 5) >
    full_board
    full_and_sunday
    full_board_and_day
    ...
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, do you want to show this on the front-end and update the value as the user changes his choices or do you want to get this value in the back-end and do something with it there or add it to the response ?

Comment: I want to show this on the front-end. But don't using js. After submited the form the page will reload and the number of checked items have to change to a new value.

Comment: You will need to count the values in the controller and a a twig variable on the front end. I'll try and get you a code sample when I get back in front of a computer

Comment: Did you found the example?